# Deep searching through a collection with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array with objects like so:

```
[ 
    { phase: 1, fields: [ { id: 1, type: 'string' }, { id: 2, type: 'date' } ] }, 
    { phase: 2, fields: [ { id: 3, type: 'date' }, { id: 4, type: 'date' } ] }, 
    { phase: 3, fields: [ { id: 5, type: 'string' }, { id: 6, type: 'date' } ] }, 
    { phase: 4, fields: [ { id: 7, type: 'date' }, { id: 8, type: 'string' } ] }, 
]
```

I want to search through this array and return an array with only the fields that have type `date`.

I have been looking at the lodash functions `filter` and `where` but it seems filter can only look through items one level deep, whereas my array has multiple levels and my search criterium is in the second level of the array. What would be the best strategy to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a lodash chaining approach:

```
_(coll)
  .pluck('fields')
  .flatten()
  .filter({ type: 'date' })
  .value();
```

The [pluck()](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) call builds an array of all the `field` values, which are also arrays. This is why we call [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) next - to make one big array. Then it's easy to use [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) to get what you need.

Comment: This is even cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `reduce` function and use `where` in it :

```
var elements = array.reduce(function(previous, current) {
    return previous.concat(_.where(current.fields, { type : 'date' }));
}, []);
```

Lodash version :

```
var elements = _.reduce(array, function(previous, current) {
    return previous.concat(_.where(current.fields, { type : 'date' }));
}, []);
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for. Thank you!