# Find value in multidimensional array. 3 levels deep

Tags: javascript

I have an array more or less like this

```
questionnaires[
    {
        'id': 14,
        question_asked_groups: [
            {
                'id': 11,
                questions_asked: [
                   {
                      'id': 10,
                      'list_id': 147,
                      'answer': "A lot of the time"
                   },
                   {
                      'id': '11',
                      'list_id': 148,
                      'answer': "Quite often"
                   },
                ]
            },
            {
                'id': 22,
                questions_asked: [
                   {
                      'id': 13,
                      'list_id': 188,
                      'answer': "Never"
                   },
                   {
                      'id': '14',
                      'list_id': 190,
                      'answer': "Yesterday"
                   },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

I need to set the correct button (answer) as active.
The array is a collection of all answered questions structured in a array as
`questionnaire` -> `question_asked_groups` -> `questions_asked`

So while loading the screen with all the buttons, when any button is loaded I want to take its id ( 147 for example ) and search for it in the `questionnaires` array and return the `answer`

Hope that makes sense. I will expand the question if you have questions.

I have tried a implementation of something I though was similar.

```
_find(array, list_id) {
    let object;

    array.some(function f(a) {
        if (a.list_id === list_id) {
            object = a;
            return true;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(a.items)) {
            return a.items.some(f);
        }
    });
    return object;
}
```

But cant make it work.

PS. Not sure if there is a lodash solutions for this type of thing. I have seen solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34659704/2240163) but fails aswell.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714938/lodash-property-search-in-array-and-in-nested-child-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first `map` to an array of arrays of the `question_asked_groups`, and then flatten with `.flat` - then, you can find the right object with `.find`:

```js
const questionnaires=[{id:14,question_asked_groups:[{id:11,questions_asked:[{id:10,list_id:147,answer:"A lot of the time"},{id:"11",list_id:148,answer:"Quite often"}]},{id:22,questions_asked:[{id:13,list_id:188,answer:"Never"},{id:"14",list_id:190,answer:"Yesterday"}]}]}];

const allQuestionsAsked = questionnaires.map(
  ({ question_asked_groups }) => question_asked_groups.map(
    ({ questions_asked }) => questions_asked
  )
).flat(2);
console.log(
  allQuestionsAsked.find(({ list_id }) => list_id === 147).answer
);
```

For older browsers, either include a polyfill, or use a different method:

```js
const questionnaires=[{id:14,question_asked_groups:[{id:11,questions_asked:[{id:10,list_id:147,answer:"A lot of the time"},{id:"11",list_id:148,answer:"Quite often"}]},{id:22,questions_asked:[{id:13,list_id:188,answer:"Never"},{id:"14",list_id:190,answer:"Yesterday"}]}]}];

const allQuestionsAsked = [];
questionnaires.forEach(
  ({ question_asked_groups }) => question_asked_groups.forEach(
    ({ questions_asked }) => allQuestionsAsked.push(...questions_asked)
  )
);
console.log(
  allQuestionsAsked.find(({ list_id }) => list_id === 147).answer
);
```

Comment: Sounds like your environment is not very up-to-date. Use a polyfill, or flatten some other way